In UVM can we override base_test with base1_test ? with everything else remaining same?
I have a testbench with 10s of tests(files) that derive from my 'base_test' (base_test extends uvm_test).
say I add a special mode 'base_1_test', where 'base_1_test' is derived from 'base_test'. Now when I am in that special mode I want all the "tests" to derive from 'base_1_test'.
In that 'mode', is there a way to always override 'base_test' by 'base_1_test' so that I avoid touching all the "test files". (factory overides on base_test ?).
(that special mode has a separate compilation options).
one method would be to touch all files
`ifdef special_mode
 test1 extends base_1_test;
`else 
 test1 extends base_test;
`endif. 

But that involves updating lot of files and not scalable for future updates. Hence looking for a more graceful way of doing this.

What you are asking for is called Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) and doesn't exist in SystemVerilog
The quick and easy way to do this is renaming base_test to base_1_test in your special mode
`ifdef special_mode
  `define BASE_TEST base_1_test
`else 
  `define BASE_TEST base_test
`endif
class `BASE_TEST extends uvm_test;
   `uvm_component_utils(`BASE_TEST);

Then include your extension to that BASE_TEST as base_test
`ifdef special_mode
  `include "extended_base_test.svh"

which has
class base_test extends base_1_test;

But the more scalable way of doing this is using the OOP Strategy Design Pattern. Basically you encapsulate the behaviors you want to override as virtual methods in independent classes. Without knowing exactly what behaviors you want to modify, it would be better to look at some references.
The Strategy Pattern in SystemVerilog
Design Patterns by Example for SystemVerilog Verification Environments Enabled by SystemVerilog 1800-2012
How To Code Efficiently In SystemVerilog Without AOP
